# Circular Definitions in yaml

Tags: serialization, yaml

I'm trying to use yaml to represent a train network with stations and lines; a minimum working example might be 3 stations, connected linearly, so `A<->B<->C`. I represent the three stations as follows:

```
---
stations:
    - A
    - B
    - C
```

Now I want to store the different lines on the network, and where they start/end. To do this, I add a lines array and some anchors, as follows:

```
---
stations:
    - &S-A A
    - &S-B B
    - &S-C C
lines:
    - &L-A2C A to C:
        from: *S-A
        to: *S-C
    - &L-C2A C to A:
        from: *S-C
        to: *S-A
```

and here's the part I'm having trouble with: I want to store the next stop each line at each station. Ideally something like this:

```
---
stations:
    - &S-A A:
        next:
            - *L-A2C: *S-B
    - &S-B B:
        next:
            - *L-A2C: *S-C
            - *L-C2A: *S-A
    - &S-C C:
        next:
           - *L-C2A: *S-B
```

(the `lines` array remains the same)

But this fails - at least in the Python yaml library, saying `yaml.composer.ComposerError: found undefined alias 'L-A2C'`. I know why this is - it's because I haven't defined the line yet. But I can't define the lines first, because they depend on the stations, but now the stations depend on the lines.

Is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congradulations! You found an issue in most (if not all) YAML implementations. I recently discovered this limitation too and I am investigating how to work around (in Ruby world). But that's not going to help you. What you are going to have to do is store the "next stops" as a separate set of data points.

```
next-stops:
  *S-A:
    - *L-A2C: *S-B
  *S-B:
    - *L-A2C: *S-C
    - *L-C2A: *S-A
  *S-C:
    - *L-C2A: *S-B
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll have to do it this way then, although it isn't perfect. Is this a shortcoming of YAML libraries or the spec itself?